# Identar e colorir código VB.Net

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net

Existe algum JS ou/e CSS que seja capaz de indentar e colorir código VB.net dentro de uma `div` ou `input`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe a [**Highlight**](https://highlightjs.org/), uma biblioteca Javascript:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.1.0/styles/default.min.css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.1.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

<pre><code class='vbnet'>
Imports System

Public Class Example
    Private Shared Function EndsWithS(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        If (s.Length > 5) AndAlso (s.Substring(s.Length - 6).ToLower() = "S") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Class
</code></pre>
```

Se quiser suportar somente o vb.NET, na página de [download](https://highlightjs.org/download/) é possível criar um script customizável contendo somente as linguagens de sua preferência.

Também existem [outras cores](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/tree/master/src/styles) para realçar a sintaxe, exemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/styles/zenburn.css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.1.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

<pre><code class='vb'>
Imports System

Public Class Example
    Private Shared Function EndsWithS(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        If (s.Length > 5) AndAlso (s.Substring(s.Length - 6).ToLower() = "S") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Class
</code></pre>
```